# Saves file relatively in c++

Tags: c++, save, directory

I would like to save a string.
If I have the following directory structure:

```
.
└── folder1
    ├── folder2
    │   └── myCode.cpp
    └── saved_forms
```

How can I save my string in the file `Circle.txt` in `saved_forms`? For now I'm doing :

```
ofstream fichier("Circle.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
```

and it saves `Circle.txt` in `folder2`.

Comment: Try using `"../Circle.txt"`

Comment: I forgot a line in my question, I just edited it ^^ Yes i know "../name.txt", thanks for the answer anyway, that's my bad.

Comment: It all depend on the programs current working directory when you run it. The solution for the specific working directory you have detailed in the question have been posted by many, but if the current working directory is something else then that path will no longer work. That's why you normally should try and avoid fixed compile-time relative paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "../saved_forms/Circle.txt". It goes one folder level above the current folder, then goes to the saved_forms folder and creates the "Circle.txt" there.

```
ofstream fichier("../saved_forms/Circle.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

File is saved relatively to current working directory. If it always runs from `folder1/folder2/`, then use just `ofstream fichier("../Circle.txt", ios::out | ios::app)`